# SQL join 3 tables with one having a SUM column

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am sure this is simple but I am struggling to figure out how to make this work.  I have three tables:

1 temporary table and 2 other tables

Below are the table makeups:

**newartbl (custid is unique) -** 
custid, assigned, newBalance

**jobbooktbl (leadid is unique) -**
leadid, price

**paymentstbl (no unique column) -**
custid, amount

custid=leadid=custid

Here is what I have tried and is not working:

```
$sqlnewbal = "SELECT b.custid, j.price, b.assigned, SUM(p.amount) AS sumAmnt
              FROM jobbooktbl j, newartbl b, paymentstbl p
              WHERE j.leadid=b.custid AND b.custid=p.custid";
$qrynewbal = mysqli_query($db,$sqlnewbal);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qrynewbal)) {
  $custid = $row['custid'];
  $price = $row["price"];
  $paid = $row['sumAmnt'];
  $assigned = $row['assigned'];
  $newPaid = $paid/$assigned;
  $newPrice = $price/$assigned;
  $newBal = $newPrice-$newPaid;

  $usqlUpdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE newartbl SET newBalance=? WHERE custid=?");
  $usqlUpdate->bind_param('di',$newBal,$custid);
  $usqlUpdate->execute();
}
```

This is outputting null.

The expected result is to sum the amount column from paymentstbl with the custid that matches the other two tbls I want to take the SUM and subtract it from the price column of the jobbooktbl then insert the new value into the temporary table.

I am sure I am missing something simple but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

**UPDATE**

Just realized I didn't explain the division.  Some of the custid's are shared and I want to find the price and amount paid for each assigned.

Sample data:

**newartbl -**

```
custid | assigned | newBalance
   1   |    1     |    Null
   2   |    2     |    Null
```

**jobbooktbl -**

```
leadid | price
   1   | 9400
   2   | 3000
```

**paymentstbl -**

```
custid | amount
   1   |  400
```

The expected result from the sql should be

**newartbl -**

```
custid | assigned | newBalance
   1   |    1     |    9000
   2   |    2     |    1500
```

What is actually happening is

```
custid | assigned | newBalance
   1   |    1     |    Null
   2   |    2     |    Null
```

**Here is the solution I came up with....not elegant by any means:**

```
$sqlnewbal = "SELECT b.custid, j.price, b.assigned
                FROM jobbooktbl j, newartbl b
                WHERE j.leadid=b.custid";
  $qrynewbal = mysqli_query($db,$sqlnewbal);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qrynewbal)) {
    $custid = $row['custid'];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $assigned = $row['assigned'];
    $newBal = $price/$assigned;

    $usqlUpdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE newartbl SET newBalance=? WHERE custid=?");
    $usqlUpdate->bind_param('di',$newBal,$custid);
    $usqlUpdate->execute();
  }

  $sqlnewbal = "SELECT b.custid, b.assigned, b.newBalance, SUM(p.amount) AS sumAmnt
                FROM paymentstbl p, newartbl b
                WHERE p.custid=b.custid";
  $qrynewbal = mysqli_query($db,$sqlnewbal);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qrynewbal)) {
    $custid = $row['custid'];
    $paid = $row["sumAmnt"];
    $price = $row["newBalance"];
    $assigned = $row['assigned'];
    $newPaid = $paid/$assigned;
    $newBal = $price-$newPaid;

    $usqlUpdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE newartbl SET newBalance=? WHERE custid=?");
    $usqlUpdate->bind_param('di',$newBal,$custid);
    $usqlUpdate->execute();
  }
```

Comment: check for errors on the queries with `mysqli_error($db)` is there anything that comes up? also make sure that the columns have the right types to do math with, as in integers etc.

Comment: 1. Check your maths here:
$newPaid = $paid/$assigned; $newPrice = $price/$assigned; $newBal = $newPrice-$newPaid;
2. Check your Database foreign keys

Comment: No errors are occurring, columns are doubles and int so the math should not be an issue.

Comment: Aside he is using the old join styles (you should change that), I bet that the problem itself is about the joining data, which probably is turning in not having data that will attend the joins. Add some sample data on your question so we can see why it is returning 0 rows

Comment: `var_dump()` the whole thing and see what shows or not and compare those values with what are in your tables.

Comment: I have updated the question to include example data showing what I expect to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: `bind_param('di'` why are you using a double here, why not just `i`? we don't know what the column types are. and did you run a var dump as I asked?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I var dump - that is at the bottom listed as "what is actually happening"  I am using a double because some of the prices have cents not just even dollar amounts.

Comment: I figured it out...not very elegant but it works.  I just divided the process into two separate SQL statements instead of one and it works.  Thanks for taking a look and trying to help me through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a pure SQL solution without a PHP loop. MySQL can run a join on `UPDATE` statements where you can update by an aggregate subquery. Do note you query is adjusted to use explicit `JOIN` and full `GROUP BY`, both of which are ANSI-92 (industry standards) compliant:

```sql
UPDATE newartbl n

INNER JOIN
  (SELECT b.custid, j.price, b.assigned, SUM(p.amount) AS sumAmnt
   FROM jobbooktbl j
   INNER JOIN newartbl b
     ON j.leadid = b.custid
   INNER JOIN paymentstbl p
     ON b.custid = p.custid
   GROUP BY b.custid, j.price, b.assigned) sub

ON n.custid = sub.custid

SET n.newBalance = (sub.price / sub.assigned) - (sub.sumAmnt / sub.assigned);
```